# `The model Block is already registered` error when tried to refine the admin site

Tags: django

I registered a data model `Block` I had defined

```
admin.site.register(Block)
```

Additionally, I intend to make the admin site more readable:

```
class BlockAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'desc', 'admin')

admin.site.register(Block, BlockAdmin)
```

Unfortunately, encounters the error:

```
raise AlreadyRegistered('The model %s is already registered' % model.__name__)
django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model Block is already registered
```

How to revert the previous registration and implement the current?

Comment: Well why don't you remove the first `admin.site.register(Block)`?

Comment: Solved the problem by restarting the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually to revert a previous registration you made somewhere in your project - you can make simple:

```
admin.site.unregister(Block)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. Since my Model had foreign keys,
The error was resolved by registering the Models in the order in which they appear in models.py